# Rotating camera around a point on XZ plane in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, camera, rotation

I'm trying to implement a camera in OpenGL which can move around and rotate. I'd like the camera to rotate around a point on XZ plane (Y being up) that the camera is currently looking at (that is, the intersection of the XZ plane and camera's direction). What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Make a spherical camera centered at the point of intersection, if you use glm or a similar library that can compute a lookAt matrix, this is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to rotate your camera around a point `P(x, 0, z)` on the `XZ` plane

One way to do this is by calling `glRotatef(theta, px, py, pz)` which multiplies your current matrix by a rotation matrix (rotation of `theta` angles around the vector `(px, py, pz)`)

Since you want to rotate around an arbitrary point and not the origin, you'll need to translate the axes first:

```
glTranslatef(x, 0, z);
glRotatef(thetax, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(thetay, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(thetaz, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-x, 0, -z);
```

Alternatively, you could use `gluLookAt(cx, cy, cz, px, py, pz, ux, uy, uz)`, which creates a view matrix for a camera at `(cx, cy, cz)` which looks at `(px, py, pz)` with `(ux, uy, uz)` being the vector pointing "up" (the roll of the camera)

I suppose you'd want the distance of your camera to your point to remain static, so it would be convenient to express your camera's coordinates in the spherical coordinate system

`x = rsin(θ)cos(φ)`

`y = rsin(θ)sin(φ)`

`z = rcos(θ)`